# jsp welcome file not called

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a JSP web application deployed to tomcat. The url of the application is http://servername/app

The web.xml contains welcome-file-list as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="mobile" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

Now, when we access http://servername/app the application is not accessible. But, if we access the url as http://servername/app/, then the application is accessible.

I need the application to be application without the trialing / character.

Please help!

Comment: can you post whole of web.xml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can happen when you've a servlet mapped on `/` which is taking over the job of the servletcontainer's builtin default servlet who is the one responsible for going to the right root path. So either fix your servlet to do the same or map it on a more specific url pattern.

Comment: There are no servlets mapped on /. Not sure still why the index.jsp is not called.

Comment: What Tomcat version are you using? Does it have a default servlet in its own `/conf/web.xml`?

Comment: I am using tomcat v6.0.18. The conf/web.xml has servlet mapping on / to org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet

Comment: The `DefaultServlet` should redirect from `http://servetname/app` to `http://servername/app/` automatically. The symptoms can only mean that either the `DefaultServlet` is bogus or that you've another servlet mapped on `/`. Did you really untouch Tomcat's `/conf` files? Do you really not have had a servlet on `/` definied before in your `web.xml` which might still be in servletcontainer's work cache? (clean and redeploy to be sure) How are you running Tomcat? In an IDE like Eclipse? Try to configure Eclipse to take it over instead of deploying to workspace metadata.